# Salesforce - Experience Cloud - File Sharing with partners

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

Previously, when documents are uploaded in the knowledge app in the related files can be able to download by partners without any custom code of apex or Lwc/aura. This had worked when the file sharing is set by viewer. This seems to stopped working now.

We have a requirement to give a link to the partners to download the documents using a single click (direct download), without using any custom code. But when I use the download link,salesforce is promoting to login even those beside tab user is already logged in. How to download the file in a single click ?